# How can I show ${f_n(x)}$ is not equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, equicontinuity

> Let $\displaystyle f_n (x)  = \frac{x^2}{(nx -2)^4 + 2x^2}$.
> How can I show ${f_n(x)}$ is not equicontinuous ?

My Attempt : We have to show for every $\epsilon >0$ , we will get a $\delta >0$  such that for $x , y$ satisfying $|x - y| < \delta$ will also satisfy $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < \epsilon $ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

I do not know how to show this for the given function.

Comment: Isn't the given condition that of being equicontinuous?

Comment: A good way to start would be to write down what it means for a set of functions not to be equicontinuous. That is, take the definition of equicontinuity and negate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For each $n\in\Bbb N$, $f_n(0)=0$ and $f_n\left(\frac2n\right)=\frac12$.